# Youtube api does not load on firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube, youtube-api

I have the following code snippet that controls an embedded youtube player. It works great on Chrome and Safari but not on Firefox.

jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/fuSSn/4/

Code from my app:

the iframe:

```
<div class="tubeframe" id="video-frame-155" style="">
<iframe title="YouTube video player" width="350" height="262"      src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/hc5xkf9JqoE?HD=1;rel=0;showinfo=0;autohide=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="" id="video-frame-155-frame"></iframe>
</div>
```

my javascript:

```
var source_tag = document.createElement("script");


var first_source_tag = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
first_source_tag.parentNode.insertBefore(source_tag, first_source_tag);


// This function will be called when the API is fully loaded
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
YT_ready(true)
console.log("api loaded! yikes")
}


function getFrameID(id){
var elem = document.getElementById(id);
if (elem) {
    if(/^iframe$/i.test(elem.tagName)) return id; //Frame, OK
    // else: Look for frame
    var elems = elem.getElementsByTagName("iframe");
    if (!elems.length) return null; //No iframe found, FAILURE
    for (var i=0; i<elems.length; i++) {
       if (/^https?:\/\/(?:www\.)?youtube(?:-nocookie)?\.com(\/|$)/i.test(elems[i].src)) break;
    }
    elem = elems[i]; //The only, or the best iFrame
    if (elem.id) return elem.id; //Existing ID, return it
    // else: Create a new ID
    do { //Keep postfixing `-frame` until the ID is unique
        id += "-frame";
    } while (document.getElementById(id));
    elem.id = id;
    return id;
}
// If no element, return null.
return null;
}
// Define YT_ready function.
var YT_ready = (function(){
  var onReady_funcs = [], api_isReady = false;
  return function(func, b_before){
      if (func === true) {
          api_isReady = true;
          while(onReady_funcs.length > 0){
              // Removes the first func from the array, and execute func
              onReady_funcs.shift()();
          }
      }
      else if(typeof func == "function") {
          if (api_isReady) func();
          else onReady_funcs[b_before?"unshift":"push"](func);
      }
  }
})();


var video = function ( videoid,  frameid) {
var player;
var that;
var seconds;
var duration;
var stateChangeCallback;
var update_play = 0;
  return {
    setOnStateChangeCallback: function(callback) {
      stateChangeCallback = callback;
    },
    getCurrentTime: function() {
      return player.getCurrentTime();
    },

    getPlayer: function () {
      return player;
    },
    getVideoFrameId: function () {
      return "video-frame-" + videoid;
    },
    initVideo: function (second) {
        console.log("initing")
      that = this;
      YT_ready(function(){
        var frameID = getFrameID("video-frame-" + videoid);
        console.log("creating player")
          console.log(frameID)
        if (frameID) { //If the frame exists
          console.log("frame exists")
          player = new YT.Player(frameID, {
              events: {
                  "onStateChange": that.stateChange
              }

          });
          console.log("Player Created!");
          if (second) {
            console.log(second)
            setTimeout(function() { console.log("seek to"); player.seekTo(second, false); player.stopVideo()}, 1000);
          }
        }
      });
    },
    stateChange: function (event) {
      console.log("event.data = ", event.data);
      switch(event.data) {
        case YT.PlayerState.PLAYING:
        {
          if (stateChangeCallback)
            stateChangeCallback("play", player.getCurrentTime(), player.getDuration());
            onsole.log("play");
        }
        break;
        case YT.PlayerState.PAUSED:
        case YT.PlayerState.CUED:
        case YT.PlayerState.ENDED:
        {
          if (stateChangeCallback)
            stateChangeCallback("pause", player.getCurrentTime(), player.getDuration());
          console.log("pause");
        }
        break;
      }
    },
    pauseVideo: function () {
      player.stopVideo();
      console.log('player.stopVid()');
    },
    seekTo: function(second) {
      player.seekTo(second, false);
    }
  };
};



function onStateChange(vid, action, second, total) {
if (Videos[vid]) {
  console.log( (second / total) * 100);
}
};





$(document).ready(function () {
var Videos = {};
logger.info("heyyy")
var videoId=155;
//if (videoId) {
  Videos[videoId] = video(videoId,  155);
    console.log(Videos[155])
  Videos[155].initVideo();
  Videos[155].setOnStateChangeCallback(function(action, second, total) {
    onStateChange(155, action, second, total);
  });
//}
Videos[155].seekTo(1000, false);
onStateChange(155, "start", 0, 0);
});
```

I know that the required script tags are being added, I can test that from console. I also know that onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() is actually called. But I still receive errors like

> TypeError: player.stopVideo is not a function

When I run the three lines that adds the source tag again from the web console on firefox, the api seems to load and everything starts working again.

I have been struggling with this for days and I really need help figuring out what might be wrong. If it helps my application is developed in ruby on rails but I don't think this is relevant information.

Thanks

Comment: Are you using fiddler or firebug?  Perhaps they are throwing additional errors that would be helpful.

Comment: I'm using fire bug. It's not giving any extra info.

Comment: Also using frame_api instead of player_api and onyoutubeframeapi ready instead doesn't change anything. chrome and safari work , firefox doesn't

Comment: I have written this jsfiddle to include all my code: http://jsfiddle.net/fuSSn/4/   youtube api doesn't load at all in the jsfiddle so it's not exactly what's happening on my browser

Comment: Works for me in both Chrome & Firefox on a Mac.

Comment: the video seeks to second 1000?! when it gets opened? what version of firefox are you on? are you sure it's not because the api has been cached on your browser. I am using a rails stack and I have tried this on at least three computers and it doesn't work on an updated firefox on any of them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no problem with the above code. My video was loaded in a bootstrap modal. Modal's hide property would make it invisible to firefox and firefox would not load the api at all. So I removed the modal hide class and instead of display:none I used item.css("visibility", "visible"); and item.css("visibility", "hidden"); which made firefox load the api.