# YouTube API does not appear to load in Firefox, IFrame gets loaded , but the onPlayerReady event never fires?

Tags: javascript, firefox, iframe, youtube

I am loading the YouTube player API as follows:

```
      var player;
  function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
console.log("iframe ready");
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
      height: '390',
      width: '640',
      events: {
        'onReady': onPlayerReady,
        'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
      }
    });
  }


function onPlayerReady(){
console.log("player ready");
}
```

On chrome both the IFrame ready and the player ready events get fired, but on Firefox, only the iframe ready gets fired, and I never see the onPlayerReady event fire.

I was wondering what the possible causes of this issue are, and whether or not there is a workaround. I am unable to access player functions such as loadPlaylist due to this issue.

Thanks

Comment: I am experiencing same problems on Chrome. Is this problem on Google side?

Comment: Your answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17078094/youtube-iframe-player-api-onstatechange-not-firing

Answer (score 7):

In my case, the answer referenced by Ibrahim was not the issue I was facing. That's an older bug which looks to be resolved now anyways.

My video was loading in a modal window which starts out with `display:none` on it. This was preventing Firefox from fully processing the API and, and subsequently the `onReady` event wasn't firing. Safari and Chrome were behaving as expected and there were no errors to speak of so this left me scratching my head for way too long.

I changed *`display:none` to `visibility:hidden`* and the event fired and all was well with the world.

I was tipped off to this by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14556924/406171).

**EDIT:**

Internet Explorer 10 and 11 were having the same issue even after the fix mentioned above. The first comment on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15296772/406171) led me to simply use positioning (ie. `left:-150%`) to hide and show my modal, and not `visibility` or `display` attributes. Oddly enough, disabling Flash also fixed this but that's obviously not a workable solution…

Comment: Just wanted to say thank you. I had the same issue, you might just have saved me hours of head scratching.

Comment: If I could give you my lost 3 hrs of debugging, redoing everything etc. I would. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Well there is also a problem with YT flash player. But when you use HTML5 player version all YT player var and all API methods are working just fine:

```
var player;
  function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
      height: '390',
      width: '640',
      videoId: 'M7lc1UVf-VE',
      playerVars: {
        html5: 1
      },
      events: {
        'onReady': onPlayerReady,
        'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Have you also tested this yourself, in the browsers the OP mentions? Otherwise, this comment won't be very useful :)

Comment: I had a problem with youtube API. Everything was working just fine in Chrome, but Firefox does not load API and I can't access any API events including onPlayerReady etc. The problem gone once you enable HTML5 mode.